# Want to display all images as base no thumbnail required

Tags: magento-1.8

I want to display all images as base images ie (big in size) dont want to display thumbnail images how can i do this ?[image]

Answer (score 0):

First You need to verify the base, small and thumbnail image are selected in Magento admin.

admin->catalog->manage product->product->image

Then you call the image using

```
echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(163, 100);
```